# This isn't really my life story

Tags: knowledge, movies

When this man was young, Frankenstein films inspired him to take up acting, but during a performance at The Rep (L.A.) cement splashed on his face so he switched to directing for a while and there were books he wanted to abridge too.

Far from high arts and stories of class, action movies called out to him - those where he could let loose: cannons firing with a bite, the bullets whizzing behind, enemy lines of infantry yelling "Geronimo", an American legend striding out of San Francisco, pike swinging like a scythe - quick - and the dead piled up all around while the sound of mortar gets nearer.

Not everyone thought he was super - many saw him as an enemy. Oft he stated "After my first Oscar nomination I let my ego run away. Jury after jury failed to give me the top award by a narrow margin."

Don't forget short young men could succumb at 21 to the power, the absolute power of Hollywood. Many an unlucky lady has found that they are heartbreakers who want zero ties - a couple of hoosiers all night long.

The firm way he handled his first wife led to their split. Decisions regarding another woman led to thunder, fireworks and extreme measures.
He tried to explain but before the conversation had begun, forgiveness evaporated. She is typical of doctor's wives from Mississippi - burning with rage and often turning crimson.

Tides turn, though and he was still someone to look dewy at. Tear-patterns streaming down the cheeks of women were not uncommon.

Valour during his military service in his twilight years meant he was leader of the pack. Age didn't matter. He was decorated for his courageous efforts twice.

In a lifetime of travelling the world he has developed great respect for the Mexican people he met, but not for the French. Connections overseas and at home have said that he has always been great company - business conversations in March or diecast modelling of a scarecrow at night.

Move several years later and he is no longer in his prime. Cut from the A list he is no longer desired. Speaking to the media about his chances of playing leading man again, they say "No Way!".

"Outrageous" is my response.

**Question:** Who is this superstar and how many films can you find (please include the number to make it easier to check if you've got them all!)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gene Hackman movies.  I have found 49 in total (highlighted bold below).

> When this man was **young, Frankenstein** films inspired him to take
>   up acting, but during a performance at **The Rep (L.A.) cement
>   s**plashed on his face so he switched to directing for a while and
>   there were books he wanted to **abridge too.**
>
> **Far** from high arts and stories of **class, action** movies called out to him - those where he could let **loose: cannons** firing with a
>   **bite, the bullet**s whizzing **behind, enemy lines** of infantry yelling **"Geronimo", an American legend** striding out of San
>   Fran**cisco, pike** swinging like a scy**the - quick - and the dead**
>   piled up all around while the sound of mor**tar get**s nearer.
>
> Not everyone thought he was **super - man**y saw him as an **enemy.
>   Oft he state**d "After my first Oscar nomination I let my ego **run
>   away. Jury** after jury failed to give me the top award by a **narrow
>   margin**."
>
> Don't for**get short y**oung men could succum**b at 21** to the
>   **power**, the **absolute power** of Hollywood. Many an un**lucky lady** has found that they are **heartbreakers** who w**ant z**ero ties - a
>   couple of **hoosiers** **all night long.**
>
> **The firm** way he handled his first wife led to their **split. Decisions** regarding **another woman** led to th**under, fire**works and
>   **extreme measures**. He tried to explain but before the **conversation** had beg**un, forgiven**ess evaporated. S**he is t**ypical of **doctor's wives** from **Mississippi - burning** with rage and
>   often turning **crimson.**
>
> **Tide**s turn, though and he was still someone to look de**wy at. Tear-p**atterns streaming down the cheeks of women were not
>   **uncommon.**
>
> **Valour** during his military service in his **twilight** years meant he was leader of **the pack. Age** didn't matter. He was decorated for
>   his courageous efforts **twice.**
>
> **In a lifetime** of travelling the world he has developed great respect for **the Mexican** people he met, but not for the **French.
>   Connection**s overseas and at home have said that he has always been
>   great **company - business** conversations in **March or die**cast
>   modelling of a **scarecrow** at **night.**
>
> **Move s**everal years later and he is no longer in his **prime. Cut** from the A list he is no longer desi**red. S**peaking to the media about
>   his chances of playing leading man again, they say "**No Way!".**
>
> "**Out**rageous" is my response.

Comment: Well done, you got them all.

Comment: Ah, so the word "conversations" was just a coincidence?

Comment: I've just noticed you've only highlighted 48. There's one more.

Comment: I forgot to highlight "All Night Long" right after "Hoosiers"

Comment: @dennisdeems.  The Conversation is in the 5th paragraph, not in the 8th.

Answer (score 2):

List in progress

> Gene Hackman

Without googling these are the movies I have, I'll complete later if no one else does.

> The French Connection, Heartbreakers, Absolute Power, Young Frankenstein, A bridge Too Far, Power, The Runaway Jury, Loose Cannons, Mississippi Burning, Crimson Tide, Hoosiers, The Firm, The Mexican...

I'll take a look at his IMDb list later, I get the feeling they are probably all there because 80% of the words in the text remind me of a movie title, I'm just unsure if he was in all of them.